# show NavigationView MenuItems holo indicator programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-drawable

I have a navigation view that I populate dynamically according to the response I get from an API request. So I have to do most of the menu items design programmatically.

My aim is to add the indicator (yellow vertical strip) in left side when a menu item is checked, as in this picture:

[image]

Here is my code up to now:

.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/background_item"/>
```

.java

```
for (SettingsMenuItem item : items) {

                if (!item.getMenu().isEmpty()) {

                        span = new SpannableString(subItem.getTitle());
                        span.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, span.length(), 0);

                        menu.add(NONE,NONE, items.indexOf(subItem), span).setCheckable(true).setChecked(false);;
                    }
}
        menu.getItem(selectedItemID).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating custom view for **yellow vertical strip** like

```
<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"/>
```

and set gravity to parent left. Also maintain the status of clicked menu somewhere in SharedPreference so as to restore the state of clicked menu.

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. How can I add this view to the menu item programmatically? and how to set the gravity to left ?

Comment: I would suggest instead of SettingsMenuItem create your custom drawer layout since there are multiple things inside the screenshot which you mentioned. To create your custom drawer layout remove NavigationView completely and create above layout mentioned in screenshot and initialize the controls in code behind. Hope this is clear. If not let me know i will post some code snippet then